# how to parse line start with multiple key words in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse input txt file where I want to check each line start with possible multiple key words and do incremental. The input text is sql like txt and I am checking multiple key words, if found it to check the pattern in next to it. To do so, I got some help and able to parse some. But when I tried to add other possible key words, some of the lines were not parsed, and getting value error instead. I checked with `re` documentation, understood how to check line start with multiple strings, but still end up with some value error. Can anyone able to take a look and correct me?

**Use case**:

So each line, I am expecting to see one of these as starting of each line: `CREATE`, `CREATE OR REPLACE`, `END`, `INPUT`, `INPUT FROM`, `INSERT INTO`, so I do this by using @flakes help in previous post:

```
import re, os, sys
    
matcher = re.compile(r"^[(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?) | END | (INPUT (?: FROM)) | (INSERT(?:INTO))] (\S+) (\S+).*$")

with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    nlines = [v for v in lines if not v.isspace()]
    for line in nlines:
        if match := matcher.match(line):
            component, component_type, component_name = match.groups()
            print(f"{component=},{component_type=}, {component_name=}")
```

But nothing is printed out, I check this pattern at https://regex101.com but end up with this value error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

I used this [input file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/392b6856410e32eac79ce7a9ab29107b/raw/1787d7da12995e3371cad390af9b935eb4a9c290/input.txt) for parsing using `re`.

**objective**

Basically, I need to check each line to see whether it start with `CREATE`, `CREATE OR REPLACE`, `END`, `INPUT`, `INPUT FROM`, `INSERT INTO`, if yes, then print next word, check pattern of next next word of the key word. Can anyone point me out what went wrong with the pattern that I composed?

Comment: `match.groups()` is returning a tuple, of `len == 2`. You are assigning `_`, `component_type`, and `component_name` to the elements in this tuple. So python expects the tuple to be `len == 3`, but it's actually only 2.

Comment: @abinitio updated and that's not the issue.

Comment: Did you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/iYgoHW/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird right, now patterns is correct, thank you very much; but it is still giving me value error. because I want to print out next word, next next word after we parse the line with given pattern.

Comment: @beyond_inifinity the next word is in capture group 1 which you can get from a match object  like `m.group(1)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I updated the pattern with `r"^(?:CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?|END|INPUT FROM|INSERT INTO) (\S+) (\S+).*$"`, and run above, but still end up with `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`. Would you mind to post your answer so I could accept and endorse your effort?

Comment: @Thefourthbird can we do this like `r"^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?|END| INPUT(?:FROM)? |FROM|INSERT(?:INTO) (\S+) ?(\S*)"`, is that legit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to return 3 groups, you can make the last group capture optional non whitespace chars as that value is not always present in the example data.

You should use a single capture group for all the variants at the start of the string, and put the optional groups in a non capture group.

Note that you should not put the intented groupings in square bracktes, as they will change the meaning to a character class matching the characters that are listed in it.

The updated pattern:

```
^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?|END|INPUT FROM|INSERT INTO) (\S+) ?(\S*)
```

See the capture groups in the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g154Xd/1)

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(r"^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?|END|INPUT FROM|INSERT INTO) (\S+) ?(\S*)")

with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    nlines = [v for v in lines if not v.isspace()]
    for line in nlines:
        if match := matcher.match(line):
            component, component_type, component_name = match.groups()
            print(f"{component=},{component_type=}, {component_name=}")
```

Output

```
component='CREATE',component_type='application', component_name='vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi'
component='CREATE',component_type='FLOW', component_name='flow_src_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi;'
component='CREATE OR REPLACE',component_type='SOURCE', component_name='comp_src_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi'
component='END',component_type='FLOW', component_name='flow_src_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi;'
component='CREATE',component_type='FLOW', component_name='flow_tgt_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi;'
component='CREATE',component_type='STREAM', component_name='vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi_text_clean_stream'
component='CREATE',component_type='STREAM', component_name='CQ_STREAM_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi'
component='CREATE OR REPLACE',component_type='TARGET', component_name='comp_tgt_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi'
component='INPUT FROM',component_type='vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi_text_clean_stream;', component_name=''
component='CREATE OR REPLACE',component_type='CQ', component_name='CQ_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi'
component='INSERT INTO',component_type='CQ_STREAM_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi', component_name=''
component='CREATE OR REPLACE',component_type='OPEN', component_name='PROCESSOR'
component='INSERT INTO',component_type='vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi_text_clean_stream', component_name=''
component='END',component_type='FLOW', component_name='flow_tgt_vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi;'
component='END',component_type='application', component_name='vat4_sac_rec_cln1_tst_noi;'
```